# Searching with comma-seperated string in ElasticSearch Query, Indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to search with a string, containing multiple strings that are *comma-separated*. [might not match with the whole value text, can be partial, the passed item should be in the text]

Note: I have tried n-gram as well, which does not give me right data.
(Example: search term "Data Science" gives all "Data", "Science", "data science")

Doc In ES:

```
{
                "_index": "questions_dev",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "188",
                "_score": 6.6311107,
                "_source": {
                    "questionId": 188,
                    "questionText": "What other social media platforms do you use on your own time?",
                    "domainId": 2,
                    "subdomainId": 25,
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "difficulty": 1,
                    "time": 600,
                    "domain": "Domain Specific",
                    "subdomain": "Social Media Specialist",
                    "skill": ["social media"]
                }
            }
```

**What I have done so far:**

**Index**:

```
{
     "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "default": {
                    "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "custom_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",   
                    "pattern": ",",
                },
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "questionId": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "questionText": {
                "type": "text",
            },
            "domain": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "subdomain": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "type":{
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "difficulty":{
                 "type": "keyword"
            },
            "totaltime":{
                 "type": "keyword"
            },
            "domainId":{
                 "type": "keyword"
            },
            "subdomainId":{
                 "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query**:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["questionText","skill"],
                        "query": "social media"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 6.6311107,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "questions_development",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "188",
                "_score": 6.6311107,
                "_source": {
                    "questionId": 188,
                    "questionText": "What other social media platforms do you use on your own time?",
                    "domainId": 2,
                    "subdomainId": 25,
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "difficulty": 1,
                    "time": 600,
                    "domain": "Domain Specific",
                    "subdomain": "Social Media Specialist",
                    "skill": []
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Goal:**

Search with a string for all the docs, which contains the string.
Example:

If I search with `"social media"` it should return me the above doc.
(for my case its not returning.)

this search also should support a comma-separated search mechanism.

which means, I can pass "social media, own time" and I'm expecting the output to have `questionTexts`  text to contain any of these strings.

Comment: so what is your exact query? can u summarize it?

Comment: Is your mapping correct?  I see that you are using tokenizer as search analyzer.

Comment: @Gibbs ahh, so I have updated the indexing in question.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I have updated the question Goal section. basically the goal is to search the comma-separated string in 2 fields. right now. if I pass the whole exact text its returning data, or else not.

Comment: Something is missing in the question. First query works

Comment: @Gibbs the first query gives me nothing unless I search with the full/whole text. which means its somehow doing the exact match. any idea on this? any kind of insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The data which you are indexing  `social media, own time`, contains whitespace between `,` and `own time`. So, the tokens generated with your previous mapping are :

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": " social media",  <-- note the preceding whitespace here
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 12,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": " own time",   <-- note the preceding whitespace here
        "start_offset": 13,
        "end_offset": 22,
        "type": "word",
        "position": 1
    }
]
```

}

Therefore, in the search query when you `"query": "social media"`, with no whitespace, in the beginning, no search results are shown. However, if you query in this way `"query": " social media"` (including whitespace in the beginning), then search result will be there.

**To remove leading and trailing whitespace from each token in a stream you can use [Trim Token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-trim-tokenfilter.html#analysis-trim-tokenfilter)**
Adding working example with index data, mapping and search query

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trim"                            <-- note this
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ",",
          "filter": [
            "trim"                            <-- note this
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "questionText": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{ "questionText": "social media" }
{ "questionText": "social media, own time" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "questionText"
            ],
            "query": "own time"    <-- no whitespace included in the 
                                       beginning
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.60996956,
    "_source": {
      "questionText": "social media, own time"
    }
  }
```

**Update 1:**

**Index Settings**

```
    {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "questionText": "What other platforms do you use on your ?"
}
{
    "questionText": "What other social time platforms do you use on your?"
}
{
    "questionText": "What other social media platforms do you use on your?"
}
{
    "questionText": "What other platforms do you use on your own time?"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": "questionText",
                    "query": "social media, own time"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-index3",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 2.5628972,
    "_source": {
      "questionText": "What other social media platforms do you use on your own time?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-index3",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.3862944,
    "_source": {
      "questionText": "What other social media platforms do you use on your?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "my-index3",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 1.3862944,
    "_source": {
      "questionText": "What other platforms do you use on your own time?"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @Saikat Chakrabortty did u get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from u ?

Comment: sorry for the delay,even after doing this I'm not getting the expected result. if I search with "social media" it should give the object mentioned in the question, but output is coming empty.

i tried searching with `"What other social media platforms do you use on your own time?"` its giving me output.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty are you indexing `"What other social media platforms do you use on your own time?"` as index data, and then you are trying to search `social media` ?
Can you please tell exactly what data you are indexing and what you want to achieve ?
In my answer above I have indexed `social media, own time`, and when I am searching for `own time` in the search query, I get the expected results

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty what do you mean by  **object mentioned in the question** ?

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty can u please go through my updated part of answer, and please let me know if now u are able to resolve ur issue?

Comment: tried with the new update, does not work strangely. do you require any information to debug probably? let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218525/discussion-between-saikat-chakrabortty-and-bhavya).